# Split string with Javascript RegExp based on different character lengths

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

`"12345678ABCDEFGHIJKLMN2018/05/202018/05/30ABCD"`

I want to split it based on n-sized lengths: 
8 chars, 14 chars, 10 chars, 10 chars, 4 chars

So it would look like this:

```
12345678 (8 chars)

ABCDEFGHIJKLMN (14 chars)

2018/05/20 (10 chars)

2018/05/30 (10 chars)

ABCD (4 chars)
```

I know I could do this way: `/(.{8})/` then split the string and continue `/(.{14})/` and so on... But I was wondering if it is possible with on RegExp?

Comment: Why `RegExp`, why not just use `substr` since you already start/ed positions of each substring

Comment: Thats possible too, I way just curious if this is something regex can handle

Comment: you can use multiple regex sub-groups in one regex

Comment: [`^(........)(..............)(..........)(..........)(....)$`](https://regex101.com/r/k4IFRe/1)

Comment: @revo Nina Scholz answer makes more sense to look at

Comment: @NoOorZ24 Really? I don't think so.

Comment: @revo how fast can you tell number of characters in ".............." vs in ".{14}"?

Comment: @NoOorZ24 How fast could you know what `{14}` means in a regex than puting the same number of dots (a simple wildcard) together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match the length' with groups.

The result of match contains the full match and the groups. To get only the groups, this solution takes a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to a sparse array with [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) for getting an array without the first element.

```js
var string = "12345678ABCDEFGHIJKLMN2018/05/202018/05/30ABCD",
    [, ...result] = string.match(/^(.{8})(.{14})(.{10})(.{10})(.{4})$/);
    
console.log(result);
```